# jquery: :submit selector not working?

Tags: jquery

I have an html page which contains a button like this.

```
<input id="qsbButton" class="btn" type="submit" tabindex="10" value="Search" name="qsbButton" onclick="searchSubmitted();return true;"/>


$(':image,:reset,:button,:submit').unbind("click")
.bind('click',function(e){
alert("clicked!");
});

$('input:not(:submit),textarea').change(function(e){
alert("typed something!");
});
```

I expected to received "clicked!" alert but nothing...no error messages.

Comment: @trike, did the answer provided solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Inline messages are not "bound" in the traditional sense of the word depending on the browser. Thus, you cannot call `unbind` to remove them. This is the code you need to override inline functions:

```
$(':image,:reset,:button,:submit').each(function(){
    this.onclick = null;
    $(this).bind('click',function(e){ alert("clicked!"); });
});
```

And the rest of your code should function as normal.

**EDIT** This can be more "jQuery-like" if written this way, and it would probably run faster than the code shown above.:

```
$(':image,:reset,:button,:submit')
    .removeAttr('onclick')
    .click(function(e){ alert("clicked!"); });
```